# Использование html и xsl тэгов в xsl-преобразовании

Tags: html, xslt

Я использую xsl-translations в своем проекте для создания таблиц и у меня есть несколько вопросов об эффективности. Например: лучше ли использовать `xsl: element name =" span "` вместо `<span>`?

Comment: Форма `element name` нужна для задания имени в рантайме (в процессе выполнения). А если имя известно заранее, то проще задать его сразу как `<span>`.

Comment: тэг элемент позволяет также задавать атрибуты на основании условий

Answer (score 0):

Проанализировал и понял, что особой разницы нет, но теги html читаются лучше

на поизводительность особо не влияло, больше смотрел на отображение текста - тоже не коснулось изменений. Единственное , что могу отметить - в xsl:element можно создавать условия для атрибутов. Например, можно использовать для задание определенных стилей

Comment: "Проанализировал" -- по каким параметрам?

Comment: У вас есть какие то мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: Ну я тоже склоняюсь к тому, что чем короче разметка тем проще читать, но было интересно, что ещё вошло в анализ. Может вы меряли производительность или ещё какие-то аспекты интересовали.

Comment: на производительность особо не влияло, но тэг element позволяет создавать условия для аттрибутов

Comment: на поизводительность особо не влияло, больше смотрел на отображение текста - тоже не коснулось изменений. Единственное , что могу отметить - в xsl:element можно создавать условия для атрибутов. Например, можно использовать для задание определенных стилей